# How to disable specific CSS styles from Firebug/IE developer tool

Tags: html

I have the following html code:

```
<input type="text" value="test value" readonly/>
```

This input element is non-editable since it has the `readonly` attribute. But it's still possible to make this field editable by inspecting the element using the Firebug tool in Firefox. Is there any way to make this attribute non-editable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really not possible.  Someone will find a way around it because your code is executed on the client.  Even if you secured the client (web browser) there is still a way to post back and tamper with read-only fields using a proxy server like [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/home).  You have two choices.

1)Remove the item from the field list and make it a text element.  This is only a valid solution if you don't need the information back in the POST.

2) Keep the item read only (or hidden) but check the content has not changed on the server side.  This is a best security practice anyway.  You should always validate on the server even if you validate on the client.  The reason is that people can work aound client side validation.  There are different approaches for server side validation according to your back end language.  In this case,  if you are using PHP or ASP.NET, then you can stick the value in a session variable before you serve the page and check the POSTED value against the session value when the form is submitted.